# probability of universally true events

Tags: probability

I've got an argument with few friends about a probability question.Is there any difference between below 2 statements? & what are their respective answers?

1) What is the probability that 1 is a natural number ?

2) What is the probability that 1 is a natural number,if it is known that 1 is a natural number ?

The Dilemma is as follows:

In some coin toss questions, it is explicitly mentioned that first toss is a known head,& that affects the probability. So similarly, for above question, '1 is a natural number' should be known only if explicitly mentioned, or is it implied because it is a universal truth ?

Comment: We want to find the probability of what presumably is intended to be an event. What is the sample space? What is the probability distribution?

Comment: change friends :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the sample space is the point of argument.I believe it should be "it is a natural number" or "it is not a natural number", ie two possible outcomes.

Comment: There is often a "natural" sample space associated with a probability problem, but in general the sample space is highly non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1$ *is* a natural number the probability of it being a natural number is $100\%$, no matter whether it is known or not. So there is no difference between what the questions are asking and the valid answer is that it is a probability of $100\%$.